# A few questions on Written Expression

Tags: tense, pronouns

I am just practising some English grammar related questions; here are the questions I am confused about:

**Question:** Identify the one bold word or phrase that must be changed in order for the sentence to be correct.

1. Charleston, West Virginia, was named **for** Charles Clendenin **who** son George **acquired** land at the junction of tile Elk and Kanawha **rivers** in 1787.

A) for

B) who

C) acquired

D) rivers

Its correct answer is "B) who". Why?

2. Eleanor Roosevelt **set** the standard against which the **wives** of **all** United States Presidents since **have evaluated**.

A) set

B) wives

C) all

D) have evaluated

Its correct answer is "D) have evaluated". Why?

Answer (score 1):

1) The correct pronoun to describe "belonging to" (in your example the son of Charles Clendenin) is "whose", so "who" would not be correct.

> The town was named for Charles, **whose** son George acquired the land...

2) The wives of United States Presidents have not evaluated (i.e. they are not the **subject** of the sentence), but they have **been** evaluated (rather, they are the **object** of the sentence).

> The standard against which the wives of all United States Presidents since have been evaluated...